# Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect

What is the difference between calling `Response.Redirect` from the codebehind of a page, versus calling `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` from a shared method on another class?

When I call `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect` it is giving me a 404 error sometimes, when calling `Page.Respsone.Redirect` doesn't.

EDIT:

Oops, my mistake, it was a typo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference between the two methods (the getter for `Page.Request` simply returns a reference to `HttpContext.Current.Request` - you have to dig a bit in Reflector but it's there) - the `HTTP404` you see as a result is the response from the server and is totally dependent on the value passed to the `Redirect` method.

Comment: I agree- By looking at the Web server logs it should be easily apparent why the 404 is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

You'll only get the 404 error if your URL points to a non-existent page.  These two methods are the same, it's your code that'll be the problem.